# How to turn a bokeh graph's html output into a pdf

Tags: python, jinja2, google-colaboratory, bokeh, weasyprint

I have created a graph using bokeh in google colab and wish to embed it into a PDF (as part of a jinja2 template). The Jinja2 html output shows in the pdf except for the bokeh graph.

When I try and convert just the bokeh plot I just get a blank page:

`from weasyprint import HTML`

`HTML('bokeh-test.html').write_pdf("report3.pdf")`

Is there a way to get Weasyprint to work with Bokeh's html output?
I'm using google-colab so there is a limit to what I can install.
I used https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf to convert the html to a pdf and it shows the graph.

Bokeh graph html output:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  
  <head>
    
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Bokeh Plot</title>
      
      
        
          
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.css" type="text/css" />
        
        
          
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.bokeh.org/bokeh/release/bokeh-0.13.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            Bokeh.set_log_level("info");
        </script>
        
      
      
    
  </head>
  
  
  <body>
    
      
        
          
          
            <div class="bk-root" id="ef113f06-aa36-4375-be30-7e11ddafa77a"></div>
          
        
      
      
        <script type="application/json" id="4ee5c914-fee4-4720-8c61-acaf6a1f5e0b">
          {"57a9d4e3-e61b-42d1-9e38-2d3437421187":{"roots":{"references":[{"attributes":{"bottom_units":"screen","fill_alpha":{"value":0.5},"fill_color":{"value":"lightgrey"},"left_units":"screen","level":"overlay","line_alpha":{"value":1.0},"line_color":{"value":"black"},"line_dash":[4,4],"line_width":{"value":2},"plot":null,"render_mode":"css","right_units":"screen","top_units":"screen"},"id":"517c2134-ed27-444c-915e-3ffb477d5f1c","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"attributes":{"data_source":{"id":"5431ac6b-2caf-4a54-b371-e853e6bd7a1f","type":"ColumnDataSource"},"glyph":{"id":"7d8c79a4-27fd-4fee-ba41-e68b7308b250","type":"VBar"},"hover_glyph":null,"muted_glyph":null,"nonselection_glyph":{"id":"04df65f3-0a25-4a1f-b75b-70d459e720eb","type":"VBar"},"selection_glyph":null,"view":{"id":"f7508f8e-52c6-4a67-864a-e1d20de6373d","type":"CDSView"}},"id":"178d9ac7-fe8f-4c12-ae2b-27c0630e9bfe","type":"GlyphRenderer"},{"attributes":{"overlay":{"id":"517c2134-ed27-444c-915e-3ffb477d5f1c","type":"BoxAnnotation"}},"id":"59417e60-4616-4ceb-8cb8-0a2e8215b228","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"ab2cfea9-982a-470d-a222-7b2c43be98f3","type":"CategoricalScale"},{"attributes":{"callback":null},"id":"41aa3083-6fba-495e-b0e0-5201619117c8","type":"DataRange1d"},{"attributes":{"plot":{"id":"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"935d6bf7-1198-4252-9ed2-6e479bd5ef62","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"b8e5a61d-76cf-4647-87d0-a6bdfc08e31c","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"6941c212-764a-4b31-8412-11e0b3262395","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{},"id":"9e3d4322-4d16-4912-b0ad-79611d031253","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"factors":["2017-39","2017-40","2017-41","2017-42","2017-43","2017-44","2017-45","2017-46","2017-47","2017-48","2017-49","2017-50","2017-51","2017-52","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04","2018-05","2018-06","2018-07","2018-08","2018-09","2018-10","2018-11","2018-12","2018-13","2018-14","2018-15","2018-16","2018-17","2018-18","2018-19","2018-20","2018-21","2018-22"]},"id":"d8e79791-ca6d-4f6c-ae30-d06e808dad55","type":"FactorRange"},{"attributes":{"fill_alpha":{"value":0.1},"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_alpha":{"value":0.1},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"top":{"field":"duration"},"width":{"value":0.8},"x":{"field":"index"}},"id":"04df65f3-0a25-4a1f-b75b-70d459e720eb","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{"plot":null,"text":"Hours driven each week","text_font_size":{"value":"18pt"}},"id":"47d89887-fdc8-491c-af53-50acfc4d7385","type":"Title"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Hours","formatter":{"id":"9e3d4322-4d16-4912-b0ad-79611d031253","type":"BasicTickFormatter"},"plot":{"id":"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"0b715b2c-d93a-4787-a350-b9d270f0bd01","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"e70ed347-e9ca-4595-8959-9611cc88c2a3","type":"LinearAxis"},{"attributes":{"callback":null,"data":{"duration":{"__ndarray__":"AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAApAzczMzMzMF0AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAERERERERAJA3t3d3d3dKUAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA","dtype":"float64","shape":[36]},"index":["2017-39","2017-40","2017-41","2017-42","2017-43","2017-44","2017-45","2017-46","2017-47","2017-48","2017-49","2017-50","2017-51","2017-52","2018-01","2018-02","2018-03","2018-04","2018-05","2018-06","2018-07","2018-08","2018-09","2018-10","2018-11","2018-12","2018-13","2018-14","2018-15","2018-16","2018-17","2018-18","2018-19","2018-20","2018-21","2018-22"]},"selected":{"id":"a5b6187f-ffd1-43eb-92ca-2ed60bddcce5","type":"Selection"},"selection_policy":{"id":"c11dc4a7-7148-407e-90ac-86c53b64e997","type":"UnionRenderers"}},"id":"5431ac6b-2caf-4a54-b371-e853e6bd7a1f","type":"ColumnDataSource"},{"attributes":{},"id":"01c941d4-a31f-403a-9ba9-fc35388abc24","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"attributes":{"below":[{"id":"991d44e6-2849-4b16-8b3c-67ce9f05b42c","type":"CategoricalAxis"}],"left":[{"id":"e70ed347-e9ca-4595-8959-9611cc88c2a3","type":"LinearAxis"}],"plot_height":400,"plot_width":1000,"renderers":[{"id":"991d44e6-2849-4b16-8b3c-67ce9f05b42c","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"id":"b8e5a61d-76cf-4647-87d0-a6bdfc08e31c","type":"Grid"},{"id":"e70ed347-e9ca-4595-8959-9611cc88c2a3","type":"LinearAxis"},{"id":"00ddf32c-f48f-4cc5-ae77-64c914eb7fc5","type":"Grid"},{"id":"517c2134-ed27-444c-915e-3ffb477d5f1c","type":"BoxAnnotation"},{"id":"178d9ac7-fe8f-4c12-ae2b-27c0630e9bfe","type":"GlyphRenderer"}],"title":{"id":"47d89887-fdc8-491c-af53-50acfc4d7385","type":"Title"},"toolbar":{"id":"d7d3a411-b28c-4f3f-9c99-144f1151b83f","type":"Toolbar"},"x_range":{"id":"d8e79791-ca6d-4f6c-ae30-d06e808dad55","type":"FactorRange"},"x_scale":{"id":"ab2cfea9-982a-470d-a222-7b2c43be98f3","type":"CategoricalScale"},"y_range":{"id":"41aa3083-6fba-495e-b0e0-5201619117c8","type":"DataRange1d"},"y_scale":{"id":"40cda5bc-3a56-4c31-8fd8-14fc3c5e1880","type":"LinearScale"}},"id":"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},{"attributes":{},"id":"5de2c2ac-a957-4b3e-a38a-af1af0153811","type":"HelpTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"a5b6187f-ffd1-43eb-92ca-2ed60bddcce5","type":"Selection"},{"attributes":{},"id":"c11dc4a7-7148-407e-90ac-86c53b64e997","type":"UnionRenderers"},{"attributes":{},"id":"935d6bf7-1198-4252-9ed2-6e479bd5ef62","type":"CategoricalTicker"},{"attributes":{"fill_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"line_color":{"value":"#1f77b4"},"top":{"field":"duration"},"width":{"value":0.8},"x":{"field":"index"}},"id":"7d8c79a4-27fd-4fee-ba41-e68b7308b250","type":"VBar"},{"attributes":{"source":{"id":"5431ac6b-2caf-4a54-b371-e853e6bd7a1f","type":"ColumnDataSource"}},"id":"f7508f8e-52c6-4a67-864a-e1d20de6373d","type":"CDSView"},{"attributes":{"axis_label":"Date","formatter":{"id":"6941c212-764a-4b31-8412-11e0b3262395","type":"CategoricalTickFormatter"},"major_label_orientation":45,"plot":{"id":"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"935d6bf7-1198-4252-9ed2-6e479bd5ef62","type":"CategoricalTicker"}},"id":"991d44e6-2849-4b16-8b3c-67ce9f05b42c","type":"CategoricalAxis"},{"attributes":{},"id":"e63ed713-5f57-4972-b2f1-b47e836113be","type":"PanTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"40cda5bc-3a56-4c31-8fd8-14fc3c5e1880","type":"LinearScale"},{"attributes":{"active_drag":"auto","active_inspect":"auto","active_multi":null,"active_scroll":"auto","active_tap":"auto","tools":[{"id":"e63ed713-5f57-4972-b2f1-b47e836113be","type":"PanTool"},{"id":"01c941d4-a31f-403a-9ba9-fc35388abc24","type":"WheelZoomTool"},{"id":"59417e60-4616-4ceb-8cb8-0a2e8215b228","type":"BoxZoomTool"},{"id":"cd7c9a7f-62e7-407d-85e8-c80859cce5f0","type":"SaveTool"},{"id":"53d31065-2af5-417a-9aa5-b83dcc1ba3d3","type":"ResetTool"},{"id":"5de2c2ac-a957-4b3e-a38a-af1af0153811","type":"HelpTool"}]},"id":"d7d3a411-b28c-4f3f-9c99-144f1151b83f","type":"Toolbar"},{"attributes":{},"id":"cd7c9a7f-62e7-407d-85e8-c80859cce5f0","type":"SaveTool"},{"attributes":{"dimension":1,"plot":{"id":"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe","subtype":"Figure","type":"Plot"},"ticker":{"id":"0b715b2c-d93a-4787-a350-b9d270f0bd01","type":"BasicTicker"}},"id":"00ddf32c-f48f-4cc5-ae77-64c914eb7fc5","type":"Grid"},{"attributes":{},"id":"53d31065-2af5-417a-9aa5-b83dcc1ba3d3","type":"ResetTool"},{"attributes":{},"id":"0b715b2c-d93a-4787-a350-b9d270f0bd01","type":"BasicTicker"}],"root_ids":["68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe"]},"title":"Bokeh Application","version":"0.13.0"}}
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          (function() {
            var fn = function() {
              Bokeh.safely(function() {
                (function(root) {
                  function embed_document(root) {
                    
                  var docs_json = document.getElementById('4ee5c914-fee4-4720-8c61-acaf6a1f5e0b').textContent;
                  var render_items = [{"docid":"57a9d4e3-e61b-42d1-9e38-2d3437421187","roots":{"68a2a747-e658-4f80-bc64-925e7307eafe":"ef113f06-aa36-4375-be30-7e11ddafa77a"}}];
                  root.Bokeh.embed.embed_items(docs_json, render_items);
                
                  }
                  if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                    embed_document(root);
                  } else {
                    var attempts = 0;
                    var timer = setInterval(function(root) {
                      if (root.Bokeh !== undefined) {
                        embed_document(root);
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                      attempts++;
                      if (attempts > 100) {
                        console.log("Bokeh: ERROR: Unable to run BokehJS code because BokehJS library is missing")
                        clearInterval(timer);
                      }
                    }, 10, root)
                  }
                })(window);
              });
            };
            if (document.readyState != "loading") fn();
            else document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn);
          })();
        </script>
    
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bokeh plots are actually JavaScript applications that render to an HTML canvas, and repond and handle UI events. PDFs can't do anything with directly, since they have no capability to run JavaScript code. I very much doubt that any programmatic HTML-to-PDF tool can do anything useful with it either. AFAIK your best option will be to explicitly export PNGs using [Bokeh's export API](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/export.html):

```
from bokeh.io import export_png

export_png(plot, filename="plot.png")
```

There is also a mode that will generate SVGs in the browser, and it's possible that HTML-to-PDF tools will be able to convert this kind of output:

```
plot.output_backend = "svg"
```

However as of Bokeh 0.13 there are several limitations and known issues with SVG output in Bokeh. You would simply have to try it and see it works sufficiently for your specific use case.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have tried downloading the graphs as images however this requires using selenium and I haven't been table to get this to work in google colab. 
I was able to generate a pdf with the graph using the website https://www.sejda.com/html-to-pdf so was hoping that there would be a html - pdf library that would work although I haven't found one that will work in google colab and output the graph.
Do you know if changing the bokeh output html mode would work?
https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/resources.html#bokeh.resources.Resources

Comment: As I said you will just have to try it and see. If not, and you can't install selenium to in order to use `export_png`, then Bokeh is probably not suitable for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this (very rough) code for HTML-to-PDF conversion, which usually works even with fairly complex templatized layouts with bokeh plots embedded within. There are two engines:

1. Uses a local install of headless chromium (you can make chromium an alias for your Google Chrome executable or make a new function parameter for the path).
2. The sejda webservice API, which doesn't require any local installs (other than `pip install requests`) but does require a free account for the token, and seems to have a cap at 25 MB for the document size.

```
import os
import subprocess
import tempfile as tmp

import requests

def html_to_pdf(document, compress=False, engine='chromium',
                url='https://api.sejda.com/v2/html-pdf', token=None,
                webservice_options=None):
    """
    Convert html to pdf using headless chromium or sejda webservice.

    Optionally compress with ghostscript (also needs to be installed) if using chromium. For webservice_options,
    see https://www.sejda.com/developers#html-pdf-api for docs.

    Parameters
    ----------
    document: string
        Full html document to render.

    Returns
    -------
    pdf: bytes
        The rendered pdf document as a bytestring.

    Notes
    -----
    Unfortunately requires disk (temporary files) when using chromium engine.

    """
    if webservice_options is None:
        webservice_options = {}
    if engine == 'sejda':
        payload = {'htmlCode': document, **webservice_options}
        response = requests.post(url, json=payload, headers={'Authorization': f'Token: {token}'})
        response.raise_for_status()
        static_bytes = response.content
    elif engine == 'chromium':
        with tmp.NamedTemporaryFile('w', suffix='.html', encoding='utf-8') as interactive_file:
            interactive_file.write(document)
            interactive_filename = interactive_file.name
            static_filename = interactive_filename.replace('.html', '.pdf')

            command = 'chromium --headless --disable-gpu --audio-output-channels=0 --print-to-pdf={pdf} {html}'.format(pdf=static_filename, html=interactive_filename)
            subprocess.check_call(command.split())

            if compress:
                # needs svg to run
                small_static_filename = static_filename.replace('.pdf', '_small.pdf')
                command = 'gs -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/screen -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dQUIET -sOutputFile={pdfout} {pdfin}'.format(pdfin=static_filename, pdfout=small_static_filename)
                subprocess.check_call(command.split())

            with open(small_static_filename if compress else static_filename, 'rb') as static_file:
                static_bytes = static_file.read()

            os.remove(static_filename)
            if compress:
                os.remove(small_static_filename)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'invalid engine: {engine}')

    return static_bytes
```